# Representar valores de un array JSON, error

Tags: javascript

Estoy recibiendo unos valores en json y al hacer la comparación no lo represento bien, la condición no es correcta.
El json que recibo una vez hecha la consulta:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-24",
      "val": "0.0000",
      "mag": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-24",
      "val": "0.0477",
      "mag": 4
    },
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-24",
      "val": "1.0000",
      "mag": 5
    },
    {
      "id": 238,
      "cad": "1",
      "time": "2022-09-24",
      "val": "0.1514",
      "mag": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

Hablando por ejemplo de una enfermedad y tomando como ejemplo la magitud 5 y la 6:
supongamos que el 5 es el covid y el 6 la probabilidad de que haya covid
- la magnitud 5 puede tener dos posibles valores: 0 y 1. Si la magnitud 5 tiene el valor 1 -> represento el valor de la magnitud 6: "val": "0.1514", pero si la magnitud 5 tiene el valor 0 ya no represento el valor que tiene la magnitud 6.

```
function dise(){
    var elemento = document.getElementById("formulario");
    obje = document.getElementById('par');
    var txt='';
    txt = "\""+obje.value+"\"";
    url_obje = 'par='+txt
    par(obje.value);
}
function par(parId){ 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var url = "obPar.php";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = {par: parId}
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    var onError = function() {
        alert('error');
    }
    xhr.onerror = onError;
    xhr.onload = function(){
        xhr.responseText;
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        if(xhr.status === 200){
            var datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for(var i in datos.data){
                if(datos.data[i].mag == 5 && datos.data[i].val == 0){
                    $('#unc01').addClass('verde');
                }else if(datos.data[i].mag == 6 && datos.data[i].val >= 0.1 && datos.data[i].val <= 0.11){
                    $('#unc01,#unc03').removeClass('verde');
                    $('#unc02').addClass('verde');
                }else if(datos.data[i].mag == 6 && datos.data[i].val >= 0.11 && datos.data[i].val <= 0.16){
                    $('#unc01,#unc02').removeClass('verde');
                    $('#unc03').addClass('verde');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
}
```

creo que esta podría ser...

Comment: Yo tampoco la veia bien y la edité como codigo... así se ve bien?

Comment: ahora se ve bien! intenté editarla pero no respondía el markdown

Comment: Revisando el código... `datos.data[i].mag` o vale 5 o vale 6... pero tu estás diciendo si vale 5 entre al if, y dentro del if preguntas que si vale 6... esa condicion jamás será cierta y por eso va al rojo inmediatamente (al else). Ese es el error... y como no entiendo muy bien que es lo que quieres lograr, no se como darte alguna alternativa

Comment: Puedes colocar el JSON en su formato por favor

Comment: @Pipe edité la pregunta a ver si lo aclaraba un poco más, sería algo como: Hablando por ejemplo de una enfermedad y tomando como ejemplo la magitud 5 y la 6: supongamos que el 5 es el covid y el 6 la probabilidad de que haya covid - la magnitud 5 puede tener dos posibles valores: 0 y 1. Si la magnitud 5 tiene el valor 1 -> represento el valor de la magnitud 6: "val": "0.1514", pero si la magnitud 5 tiene el valor 0 ya no represento el valor que tiene la magnitud 6. No se muy bien como poder hacer esa comparación, intenté varias cosas pero siempre llego al mismo punto